# Save dta file with local and global variables in file name

Tags: stata, backslash, stata-macros

In Stata, I try to save a `dta` file using local and global macros together in file names.

However, the local macros are not parsed correctly.

The global macro `result` is a folder directory which is:

```
global result "C:\Users\...\....\..."
```

The local macro `x` is defined in a loop:

```
foreach x of varlist ret_yyy { 
    .......
    save "$result\Reg_Coefficients\`x'", replace
}
```

This only produces a file under a "result" folder with name "Reg_Coefficients`x'".

What I expect is to save a file under folder "Reg_Coefficients".

Comment: I find that when I add something before local "`x'" and after "Reg_Coefficients\", it works correctly.

        save "$result\Reg_Coefficients\reg_`x'" , replace

Comment: Yes, forward slashes are easier to use but placing "\\" before a local macro will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward slashes (/) instead:

```
sysuse auto, clear
global result "C:/Users/.../..../..."

foreach x of varlist * { 
    display "$result/Reg_Coefficients/`x'"
}

C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/make
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/price
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/mpg
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/rep78
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/headroom
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/trunk
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/weight
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/length
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/turn
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/displacement
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/gear_ratio
C:/Users/.../..../.../Reg_Coefficients/foreign
```

Comment: -search backslash- for why. The backslash is an escape character as well as a separator in Windows filepaths.